# cascade.detectMultiScale taking a lot of time

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I am trying to write a program in OpenCv Python to detect road signs. I have created a model and when I run the funtion it doesn't seem to end. Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

IMAGE_SIZE = 200.0
MATCH_THRESHOLD = 3

stop_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/cascade.xml')
street = cv2.imread('test/1.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(street, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

print "cascade"
objects = []
stops = stop_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor = 1.2, minNeighbors = 4, minSize = (40,40), flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
print "end"
```

I have waited up-to 15 minutes but it doesn't seem to end.

[My Project Files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1MR4Pk9DuUFenV0S1RmNUw1bEU&usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the data also?

Comment: the data had just 10 images for positive and 5 for negative cases. I have added the project files